# Need advice for database design

Tags: mysql, database, data-structures

I'd like to do some Php graphs with MySQL datas, but first I have to think about the best design for my database, I prefer ask you some advice because I'm a newbie and I think there is a better way that the one I'm thinking.

I have a main table called "companies", with an autoincrement id column and a region column, more companies and more column could be added later.
On the Php graphs, I'd like to choose the graphs by companies regions and maybe others filters later, this is why my table "companies" is the the central table.

I'd like to fetch new datas (stocks, commands, roi, etc..) for every companies one time per day and use those datas on graph. The old datas won't be overwritten but keep for the graphs history, more data I'll have more the graph will show the behavior of the company.

So, every day there will be one more row per companie (more than 200 companies in total), and this point is my issue.
I was thinking to create one table per companie and add a new row everyday on each on those tables, but I feel it's dirty and there is a better and cleaner way to do that, is anybody can show me the best way ?

Thanks for reading, I hope you'll can help me.

Comment: Create a table for each independent entity. Properties of the entity will be stored in the table. Normalize your data. Don't create a table for each company - it is a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have at least those entities in your domain:

- Companies
- Company indicators (stock, ROI, commands, ...)
- Indicator types (stock, ROI, commands, ...)
- Regions

So you should probably have something similar to the schema below:

```
             ,---------.  
,-------.    |Indicator|  
|Company|    |---------|  
|-------|    |date     |  
|name   |*---|value    |  
|-------|    |---------|  
`-------'    `---------'  
    o             o       
    |             |       
,------.   ,-------------.
|Region|   |IndicatorType|
|------|   |-------------|
|name  |   |-------------|
|------|   `-------------'
`------'
```